# Multi-Sample Reliability Data that follows Weibull Distribution

Tags: data-request, reliability

I am looking for a real-worlds `k`-sample (`k>3`) reliability data (complete not censored) that follow a two-parameter Weibull distribution with shape parameter `β` and scale parameter `θ`. I want to compare `k`  reliability function at time `t*` which is defined as `R(t*)=exp[-(t*/θ)^β]`.

Any hint, link or reference to a particular data-set would be appreciated. Preferably, data should be large enough so that Weibull distribution can be fitted by means of ML procedure.